# Why am i getting an error while trying to install ruby on Dockerfile?

Tags: ruby, docker

When I run `sudo docker build`, everything goes smoothly until ruby installation.

I get this error

```
Step 17 : RUN ruby-install ruby
 ---> Running in acfbb2c565ed
>>> Installing ruby 2.1.3 into /home/app/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3 ...
>>> Installing dependencies for ruby 2.1.3 ...
/usr/local/bin/../share/ruby-install/ruby-install.sh: line 104: sudo: command not found
!!! Installing dependencies failed!
The command '/bin/sh -c ruby-install ruby' returned a non-zero code: 255
```

This is inside of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:wily

MAINTAINER Mertcan Cam <mertcancam@gmail.com>


RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh


RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl wget ca-certificates build-essential autoconf python-software-properties libyaml-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev bison openssl make git libpq-dev  libsqlite3-dev nodejs 

RUN apt-get clean 

RUN echo %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL >> /etc/sudoers


RUN wget -O ruby-install-0.5.0.tar.gz https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/archive/v0.5.0.tar.gz && tar -xzvf ruby-install-0.5.0.tar.gz && cd ruby-install-0.5.0/ && make install


RUN wget -O chruby-0.3.9.tar.gz https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/archive/v0.3.9.tar.gz && tar -xzvf chruby-0.3.9.tar.gz && cd chruby-0.3.9/ && make install

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* /tmp/*

RUN useradd -m -G sudo app

USER app
WORKDIR /home/app

RUN ruby-install ruby
RUN rm -rf /home/app/src
```

Comment: Why not just start from official build? 
https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/

Comment: The path is borked with a replacement parameter:  `Installing ruby 2.1.3 into /hom\`enter code here\`e/app/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3`.  Whatever has inserted `\`enter code here\`` inappropriately in this path should be fixed or removed.